# Unable unzip file with the correct password

Tags: passwords, compression, zip

Before i used command "zip -eq file.zip /folder" to zip my folder with the password. Now I unzip the file with the correct password but always show "Wrong password". I also tried to use PassFab to check but strange. It note my zip file is unencrypted and doesn't have password. Anyone face this issue or any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92EKQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially create the zip file with a password, all files are encrypted with that password.

When you subsequently add files (without specifying the password) to an existing archive (which is encrypted), they get added without a password.  It's just the way these programs work.

Therefore, I suspect that you added this file to the archive at a later date and it has no password on it, while other files do require a password.

Comment: so, in case your ideas are right, how i can resolve my issue. Currently, i can not unzip with my correct password :(

Comment: For that file, try without a password.  Its easier to see this problem in a GUI interface, where you can drag and drop.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure about that, but when i click to open that file, the password must be required. if not, it shows incorrect password

Comment: If blank does not work and your password does not work, then you must have added it with another password.  Can you open other files in the archive ?

Comment: i cannot open other files in the archive, it seems to require to un-encrypt the master file

Comment: i tried to add a file and set  the other password, then i unzip with that password, "Incorrect password" also.

Comment: That sounds like you are using some illegal characters in your password.  maybe the password is truncated to that character.  Do you want to list the non alphanumeric characters you have used in any order

Comment: i use @ in my password, i remember that i already tried to unzip when i zipped the file in the past but now it doesn't work anymore

Comment: do you have any ideas about this one :( i tried a lot

Comment: What application and version are you using.  I can try it for you.